# Desktop restarting without BSOD or dump

Tags: windows-7, bsod, crash, hardware-failure, reboot

I have been experiencing random restarts on my desktop for the past week.

The restarts do not show any BSOD or errors. I have tried turning off automatic restart option on Windows as well as disabling auto restore last state on power loss in BIOS. However, it is still restarting. Sometimes it occurs before reaching BIOS, sometimes few minutes into Windows and sometimes few hours later.

In windows event viewer, I see event ID 41, task category 63. 
"The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power expectedly."
Event Data shows BugcheckCode: 0, BugcheckParameter1 to 4: 0, SleepInProgress: false, PowerButtonTimestamp: 0

I have also ran memtest86 + sfc and yield no results. I do not overclock my system too.

I have replaced the PSU and this is still occurring. Does this mean that it is my motherboard that is failing?

EDIT: I have also been logging the temperatures of my HDD, PSU and CPU, nothing out of the ordinary. I also clean out dust often.
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64 bit

Comment: `Sometimes it occurs before reaching BIOS,` That does seem to indicate a hardware issue, and not a software problem.

Comment: is there a way to find out which hardware specifically? especially motherboard

Comment: Not without spare HW parts or maybe with some kind of debug LEDs (and a way to record them). Other than spare parts (esp. PSU) the only idea I have is to check the motherboard for damaged capacitors.

Comment: kinda sucks since I'm the only desktop user at my house. Guess I'll probably get part by part to test it out. Do you happen to know if it's possible to be a failing hard disk? I will probably try from the cheapest possibility =/

Comment: A desktop should POST without a connected HDD. Thus you can disconnect the drive and see if it fails in the BIOS. Or disconnect the drive and boot from a liveUSB. If it still fails then the cause is not the HDD.

Comment: why didn't I think of that? gonna try that out. Thanks!

Comment: try the steps from this kb article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the data you provide you either have faulty hardware i.e. your motherboard or a faulty line is powering your PS.

Comment: I have swapped the cable for my PSU with monitor.  still having the same issue. Guess it's really my motherboard? is there ways to test if it's really my motherboard without having another pc?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/573359)

Comment: @Adam G replacing your cable does not rule out a problem upstream. Then you should try powering your PC from other outlet, also you can try powering other PC from the same outlet and see if the problem repeats. If it doesn't then the problem is your motherboard. Unfortunately this kind of erratic hardware failures are hard to pinpoint.

Comment: @Ctrl-alt-dlt why mine is not an answer??? I'm an EE and mine is a perfectly valid answer for an erratic hardware failure.

Comment: We don't like guesses as answers. "Could be" is what makes it a comment.

Comment: it was really a failing motherboard in this case. Thanks guys for the suggestions and help